# Vue.js component design - how to clear a prop when input changes without mutating the prop?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In our Vue.js application we have a bunch of components that are responsible for rendering everything related to a particular field. For example, one of our components is called `SelectField` and is responsible for rendering a `<select>` element, as well as a `<label>`, error message and so on.

Currently error messages are a prop defined on the component like so:

```
props: {
   ...,
   errorMessage: String
}
```

If the value errorMessage is truthy, we display the error. If it isn't we don't. Something like this:

```
<p v-if="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

The value of errorMessage is computed in the parent component, when the user clicks a button. The button code runs some validation logic, and if the validation fails, the errorMessage for that field is set to an appropriate message. Something like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            exampleError: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            if (...) {
                exampleError = "You got an error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I want to solve is how to clear the error message when the user makes a change to the component. At the moment I am solving it by doing this:

```
<SelectField
    ...
    :errorMessage="exampleError"
    @input="exampleError = ''"
/>
```

Essentially it listens for a change on `SelectField` via `@input` and then sets the error message to empty.

This works, except that I have to put it everywhere I use the component. I'm not able to make it part of the internals of the component, because `errorMessage` is a prop, and mutating props is an anti-pattern.

**Is there any way I can make this functionality the responsibility of the component without mutating the prop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a watcher to listen for changes to the prop and set the new value to a local copy of the error message.

When your component updates its state, you can clear the local copy.

```js
export default {
  props: { errorMessage: String },
  data: () => ({ error: this.errorMessage }), // initialise with the prop value
  watch: {
    errorMessage (newValue) {
      this.error = newValue // update the local error message when the prop changes
    }
  }
}
```

and in your template

```html
<p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
<select @input="error = null"> <!--  just an example -->
</select>
```

Comment: Would this be the same as directly modifying the prop, since as soon as the parent changes the value it would be overwritten? If that's the case, would this situation be an acceptable use of mutating props (i.e., we want to mutate it until the parent changes it again)?

Comment: @Caleb no, there is no mutating of the prop in this. Think of it as the component maintaining its inner state until it gets a message from its parent to update

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties to your prop.

Try this:

```
props: 
{
   errorMessage:
   { 
     type: String,
     deep: true,
     immediate: true 
   }
}
```

The key here is **deep:true** and **immediate:true**. They basically force the prop to watch for any changes.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for this? I think you're mixing up [`props`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) and [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)

Comment: I definetely am, sorry about that. Funny thing is that i've used the approach that i suggested multiple timed and it worked perfectly. You can try it for yourself, if it fails you can definetely use the deep:true and immediate:true props of watchers